# pgfplots figure not working - undefined control sequence

Tags: pgfplots

When trying to insert a tikz figure, using the code below:

```
\documentclass[]{memoir} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf}            
\usepackage{tikz}                   
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,
               automata,backgrounds,
               petri,topaths}           


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \input{OilPrices.tikz}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

```
./OilPrices.tikz:23: Undefined control sequence. []]
./OilPrices.tikz:23: Undefined control sequence. []]
./OilPrices.tikz:39: Undefined control sequence. [\end{axis}]
./OilPrices.tikz:39: Undefined control sequence. [\end{axis}]
./OilPrices.tikz:39: Missing number, treated as zero. [\end{axis}]
./OilPrices.tikz:39: Missing number, treated as zero. [\end{axis}]
```

This is how the tikz looks like:

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=731500,
xmax=736500,
xtick={731217,731582,731947,732313,732678,733043,733408,733774,734139,734504,734869,735235,735600,735965,736330,736696},
xticklabels={{2002},{2003},{2004},{2005},{2006},{2007},{2008},{2009},{2010},{2011},{2012},{2013},{2014},{2015},{2016},{2017}},
xlabel={Time (Years)},
ymin=20,
ymax=140,
ylabel={Price (\$/Barrel)},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Comparison of WTI and Brent Oil Prices},
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black}
]                                        %Line 23
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
731672  49.22\\
736451  23.68\\
};
\addlegendentry{Brent};

\addplot [color=mycolor2,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
731672  47.64\\
736420.560509554    29.56\\
};
\addlegendentry{WTI};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}                        %Line 39
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need the `pgfplots` package. And the current `pgf` version is `3.x`, not `0.96` ... and what is `\mycaption`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). For example, A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Christian. I changed the packages as the update above, which reduced the errors. But it still won't compile. Any ideas? My tikz seems good...

Comment: @Niccolo: As Andrew asked you already: Without seeing any code we can't answer this.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I just updated the question. Hope this is clearer now :)

Comment: @Niccolo: Well, the tikz code is still in an external file ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer added the tikz and removed unnecessary data points

Comment: `\figurewidth` and `\figureheigth` are not defined in the code you show. Define them and it will work.

Comment: Unrelated: You don't have to load both `tikz` and `pgf` explicitly. `pgfplots` loads them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ti*k*Z picture tries to access the undefined `\figurewidth` and `\figureheight` macros to configure the image width.

After definition and setting the lengths (please change the lengths at will) the compilation works.

```
\documentclass[]{memoir} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,
               automata,backgrounds,
               petri,topaths}           

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength{\figureheight}
\newlength{\figurewidth}
\setlength{\figureheight}{10cm}
\setlength{\figurewidth}{12cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \input{OilPrices.tikz}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The external code:

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
xmin=731500,
xmax=736500,
xtick={731217,731582,731947,732313,732678,733043,733408,733774,734139,734504,734869,735235,735600,735965,736330,736696},
xticklabels={{2002},{2003},{2004},{2005},{2006},{2007},{2008},{2009},{2010},{2011},{2012},{2013},{2014},{2015},{2016},{2017}},
xlabel={Time (Years)},
ymin=20,
ymax=140,
ylabel={Price (\$/Barrel)},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={Comparison of WTI and Brent Oil Prices},
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black}
]                                        %Line 23
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
731672  49.22\\
736451  23.68\\
};
\addlegendentry{Brent};

\addplot [color=mycolor2,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
731672  47.64\\
736420.560509554    29.56\\
};
\addlegendentry{WTI};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```